# What is the graph of $(Re \ z)^2 - (Im \ z)^2 = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do you graph $(Re \ z)^2 - (Im \ z)^2 = 0$ in a complex level. I am just thinking there is either infinite or none answer. Since $x^2-y^2=0$ does not plot a thing.

Comment: What do you mean by $x^2 - y^2 = 0$ does not plot a thing? It should be the pair of straight lines ($y = \pm x$), like a cross.

Comment: $y=x$ and $y=-x$ are lines through the origin.

Comment: So there are infinite answers since x and y are going through the origin?

Comment: What is the difference between the graph of your function and $x^2-y^2=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @RedPhoenix none?